# C# Linq query optimization problem

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose I have two large tables A and B, I want to perform a JOIN on column x of A and B (suppose they use same name) and finally select x and y from table B. Would it be faster if I just pre-select x of A and x, y of B and do JOIN on these reduced tables?

Comment: What do you mean by "pre select".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your question is when you are writing

```
select B.x, B.y
from A
join B on B.x = A.x
```

is it faster to select

```
select B2.x, B2.y
from (select x from A) A2
join (select x,y from B) B2 on B2.x = A2.x
```

The short answer is: No. For example, if you have a covering index (x,y) on B, the query will use that index instead of selecting from the full row. If you don't have a covering index, you're just wasting memory anyways if you're hoping to write the two columns to a temporary area before doing the join. In this particular case, the database will almost always optimize the two queries to the exact same execution plan anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it. You're just introducing an extra unnecessary step by doing that. You are only comparing the keys as specified in the parameters to `Join()` regardless of how many other properties are in your objects.

Answer (score 0):

No. You would do useless projections on A. If you use the "standard" query, you'll only do projections on AxB, while predoing the projection on A you'll obtain A+AxB. If we consider that A <= B (because B has a reference to A), then it's B projections vs A+B projections.